# how to determine the number of used columns in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine the number the used columns in a perticular row and shift them right. This is what I have so far but this does not seem to work. Please help.

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
LastCol = DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1), DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1).Columns.Count))
'arr(z)(1) is an integer extracted from a 2 multidimensional array           
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1), 2), DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1),LastCol))   
rng.Insert Shift:=xlRight
```

Comment: Define `does not seem to work`.  Do you get an error, unexpected behavior, what?

Comment: I get an error msg saying, "object required"

Comment: the second line in my code "LastCol = DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1), DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1).Columns.Count" is highlighted in yellow

Comment: Are there data contiguously in the cells? Or might there be gaps/blank cells?

Comment: there are no blank cells.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim LastCell as Range   
With DataSheet
    Set lastCell = .Cells(arr(Z)(1), Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    .Range(.Cells(arr(Z)(1), 2), lastCell).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
End With
```

Comment: this seems to delete my clomn A in my datasheet which i cannot have.

Comment: In that case it would help to update your question with some small sample data showing before/after. If I substitute (eg) `6` for `arr(Z)(1)` it works fine for me (assuming I understand what it is you want to do).