# How to shift a range of cells to the right

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me in shifting a defined cell range one column to the right. 
if i define

```
rng = B2:B3
```

I need a code to move my values in B2:B3 to B3:B4.

Here is what i have so far and none of this works. I get an error in the third line.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1), 2), DataSheet.Cells(arr(z)(1), LastCol))

rng.Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight '(i tried this first)
 or
rng.Offset(0, 1).Select '(I tried this second and this also did not work)
```

Comment: What is your full code, in particular what is `arr`? Plus your question as asked looks to move the values *down* one cell rather than to the right

Comment: arr is a multidimentional array. in this scenario, arr(z)(1) returns an integer which is my rowcount

Comment: @User - Please don't start duplicate questions while people are still responding to the previous one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829638/how-to-determine-the-number-of-used-columns-in-a-row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rng.Cut rng.Cells(1).Offset(0,1) 'assuming you really mean to move right
```